# How can I hack 35mm film into a 120mm camera and have it safely received?

Tags: film, diy, 35mm, medium-format

I can simply put 35mm spool in place of 120mm one. Spring will hold it all right, and I can get it to wind on the receiver spool. Of course I can't know frame number and need to do it "by the feeling", but that's all right. My problem is film changing.

35mm film on 120mm spool always gets fat roll effect, because receiver spring cannot be used - it would scratch the film. And I can't simply open camera on the field because there is no lightproof layer.

Is there any way to use empty 35mm canister for receiver spool? Or any other way to protect film while it is taken out of the camera?

Comment: A very keen man :-). Is this for "fun" or ...? | You could perhaps make a receiver with sprocket pins on the takeup roll to reduce 'fat roll effect'. As others have said - a lightproof bag works for this. A workaround I read of many moons ago is to use a jacket or coat. fold top and bottom towards front, place on ground with light entry points folded under. Kneel on one end and put arms down sleeves to access camera. Coat needs to be suitably light proof.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 
 
I have a large stock of expired but good 35mm film rolls, and my friend has a large stock of old, maybe working medium format cameras. We would prefer to use virtually free film to test them and only use new 120 film when we know it is working, at least a bit. Also, there is a wider availability of 35mm in general, and processing is cheaper, so using it purely for fun makes a lot of sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no protection from light, you just have to avoid the light. A [changing bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changing_bag) is equipment specifically developed for this purpose - you put the camera and your hands in, and extract the film by feel in the darkness of the bag.

Comment: But I need to get it out of that bag to send it for processing, right? Having it outside camera is one step, but is not sufficient. If you know a way to rewind film in that bag, back into it's original container, that may work.

Comment: You can rewind to the spool of the original cassette by rotating the spool end with fingers while hands and film are still in the bag. Once rewound, the cassette can be taken out.

Comment: Oh, OK. That does not solve fat roll and scratching issues, so not accepting yet, but may get me started. +1 and I'll keep thinking.